# Обращение к методу Activity из потока код которого в отдельном файле

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-handler

Не знаю насколько корректно я сформулировал вопрос, но он в следующем.
Есть **MainActivity** в которой есть метод **test**

```
public void test(String msg){
    textViewTest.setText(msg);
}
```

в этом же **MainActivity** я создаю поток и передаю туда **handler**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
sockedScanner scanner = new sockedScanner(selectedMAC,this,handler);
scanner.setDaemon(true);
scanner.start();
```

класс **sockedScanner** описываю в ДРУГОМ файле, если так корректно говорить конечно (создаю новый класс AndroidStudio)

```
public class sockedScanner extends Thread {}
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем. Как мне в классе **sockedScanner** вызвать метод **test** из **MainActivity**?
Пробую через **handler**, но понятно, что так не сработает.

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     test("msg");
   }
});
```

Если код **MainActivity** и **sockedScanner** разместить в одном файле то все прекрасно работает, но мне надо в разных. Есть ли какой то способ этого добиться?

Comment: Сделай интерфейс, с методом test(String msg), пусть твоя активити имплементирует этот интерфейс. Передай этот интерфейс в sockedScanner (только ради боги сделай название этого класса с большой буквы по java стаил) например через конструктор. Помни что работа с UI осуществляется только с главного потока!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Запомню это на будущее. А я решил, немного, по другому. Сделал в MainActivity Brodcast и в него отправляю сообщения из sockedScanner. Правда пришлось добавить в вызов sockedScanner this из MainActivity, так как метод sendBroadcast вызывается только при наличии context. Или можно по другому? Зато теперь не разрывается связь sockedScanner с MainActivity даже если повернуть экран. при использовании handler связь терялась (т.к. MainActivity пересоздается).

Comment: Тут уже кто-то писал про такое использование Brodcast: находясь в одной квартире открывать окна и орать друг другу через улицу :) По той же ссылке на активность, переданной в поток - вы могли бы и вызывать её методы. А при пересоздании нужно либо пересоздавать и поток (если он не нужен без активности), либо сохранять ссылку на него, "отписывать" активность, потом подписывать новую. Сейчас у вас не "не разрывается связь", а после поворота старый поток скорее всего падает из-за потери контекста старой активностью а новый создаётся и работает с новой.

Comment: Согласен, что это "крики на всю улицу". Но как сделать возврат из thread в MainActivity данных (когда thread описан в другом файле) я так и не понял. Ссылку на активность пробовал передавать в поток, но как к методам обратиться не нашел. А есть какие то "подводные камни" при таком использовании Broadcast?

Comment: Старый поток не падает после пересоздания активности. А как можно сохранить ссылку на поток (точнее где) и потом переподписать активность?

Comment: Сделал так как подсказал Михаил. Еще раз большое спасибо. И спасибо woesss за то что не дал остановиться на не очень правильном варианте решения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделал как посоветовал **Михаил**.

Создаем Интерфейс

```
public interface ScanerMessage {
    public default void msg(String msg) {
    }
}
```

затем переопределяем его в **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ScanerMessage {
    private MainActivity linkThis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        linkThis = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void mesg(String position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

после при создании потока в **MainActivity** передаем его в качестве параметра

```
sockedScanner scanner = new sockedScanner(linkThis);
```

В потоке получаем его и спокойно обращаемся к методу в **MainActivity**

```
public class sockedScanner extends Thread {
    private ScanerMessage callback;

    public sockedScanner(ScanerMessage callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        callback.mesg("Привет!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Осталось имена отутюжить и будет совсем   (`ScannerMessage`, `SockedScanner`)

Comment: Рано радовался, выяснилась непонятная мне вещь. Метод callback.mesg("Привет!"); срабатывает только в конструкторе SockedScanner, при попытке обратиться к нему в любых других методах thread приложение вылетает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Точнее не в любых, а в методе run()

Comment: Я так полагаю, что это срабатывает то о чем предупреждал Михаил "Помни что работа с UI осуществляется только с главного потока!" Но как тогда взаимодействовать с интерфейсом?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно это обойти?

Comment: Это уже тянет на новый вопрос.

Comment: Ну как бы нет. Ведь не работает как нужно.

Comment: Ваш вопрос был `Как мне в классе sockedScanner вызвать метод test из MainActivity?`. Что там в том методе, UI или может сетевой запрос? Пишите новый вопрос, приводите код, логи.